# HTML/CSS- how to align part of a cell to the left, and part to the right?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve this:

```
cell contents    :
cell contents 2  :
cell contents 32 :
```

So the "cell contents" part is left aligned, and the ":" is right aligned. I don't want to add a column with ":" in it to each row.

I know I could just add a number of:

```
&nbsp;
```

...to the markup, but wondered if there was a better solution.

Comment: CSS messes only with the 'style' part of a tag, so you will have to add the ':' at each row - that's content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your options here? Can you put more tags inside the cell and use CSS?

Such as:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <p class="left">Cell Contents</p> 
        <p class="right">:</p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </td>
</tr>

<style type="text/css">
    p.left {
      float:left;
    }

    p.right {
      float:right;
    }

    div.clear {
        clear:both;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the `:after` pseudo element, [this works in IE8+ and all other browsers](http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent).

```
td:after
{    
    content: ':';
    float: right;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m3nht/2/)</kbd>